# Codeigniter send mail using gmail is not working, just reloading

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail, codeigniter-2, sendmail

I tried to send a email using gmail server with following configurations.

```
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'dinukathilanga@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '2334444@',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'starttls'  => true,
   );

   $this->load->library('email', $config);

   $this->email->from('dinukathilanga@gmail.com', 'Dinuka Thilanga');
   $this->email->to('bbelekkaya@gmail.com');
   $this->email->subject('Email Test');
   $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

   $this->email->send();

   echo $this->email->print_debugger(); die;
```

I send mail after the form submission. But the thing is page is never ending reloading. Please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Providing your password in the example isn't a brilliant idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put that

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Between

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('dinukathilanga@gmail.com', 'Dinuka Thilanga');
```

So the final code looks similar to

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('dinukathilanga@gmail.com', 'Dinuka Thilanga');
```

It works for me.